# Cassandra column name trailing with blank characters

Tags: cassandra, hector

I have just started with Cassandra, created a simple ColumnFamily and some data using command given on [Getting started](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted) on Cassandra download page, by executing below queries.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id int PRIMARY KEY,
   fname text,
   lname text
);

INSERT INTO users (user_id,  fname, lname)
   VALUES (1745, 'john', 'smith');
INSERT INTO users (user_id,  fname, lname)
   VALUES (1744, 'john', 'doe');
INSERT INTO users (user_id,  fname, lname)
   VALUES (1746, 'john', 'smith');
```

**My Hector code for fetching data**:

```
RangeSlicesQuery<String, String, String> rangeSlicesQuery 
                = HFactory.createRangeSlicesQuery(keyspace, STR, STR, STR);
            rangeSlicesQuery.setColumnFamily(columnFamily)
            .setColumnNames(" fname ", " lname ")
            .setKeys("6", "5")
            .setRowCount(row_count);
QueryResult<OrderedRows<String, String, String>> result = rangeSlicesQuery.execute();
```

But when i fetch data using Hector API from Cassandra in Column name it contain blank space like column name fname will be: '  fname '.
And for my queries from Java Hector API i need to use same column name with blank space to fetch or save data.
Anybody have any idea, what i have done wrong, or what do i do to remove those trailing space.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the serialization/deserialization logic you use for Hector?

Comment: updated with my Hector query

Comment: FYI: you may want to take a look at the Cassandra Java driver as it will allow you to work through the native protocol instead of Thrift. https://github.com/datastax/java-driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by using "WITH COMPACT STORAGE" when creating column families.
Discussion is [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3).

Instead of Hector i used Cassandra Java Driver pointed by Allan Elder, and my problem for trailing space in column name has been solved.
Doc for how to using Cassandra Java Driver is [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/webhelp/index.html#java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientAddSession_t.html) and jars will be found by [this](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) project.
Thanks